# Is there a Terminal command that will list the current admin account?

Tags: macos, terminal

Does anyone know of a terminal command which lists the current administrator account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users who have administrative privileges on OS X belong to the group `admin`. There's no straight forward way to list members of a group as OS X uses Open Directory to manage these things and it's a bit convoluted as a result.

Here is a shell function that will give you all the members of a group. It was taken from [this SuperUser.com Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-mac-os-x):

```
members () {
  dscl . -list /Users | while read user; do
    printf "$user "
    dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "$user" -G "$*"
  done | grep "is a member" | cut -d " " -f 1;
};
```

Save that in your ~/.bash_profile or just cut and paste it to a bash or zsh prompt and then you can run:

```
members admin
```

and you'll get a list of accounts that have administrator privileges on the machine.

Comment: Now, I’m confused. I was under the impression that a `User` who is an `admin` belongs to the group `staff`

Comment: @njboot this is incorrect. You can inspect the sudo setup on an OS X machine to convince yourself of this. If you do `sudo visudo` you will see that elevated privs are available to accounts in the `%admin` group, not `%staff`. That makes the `admin` group the group you need to be in to administer an OS X machine.

Comment: @njboot for an explanation of the `staff` group see: http://superuser.com/a/20430/26633

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Reading the explanation now. Regards.

Comment: I deleted my answer, hence leaving this comment here -- the explanation you gave (as comment, on my said deleted answer) makes perfect sense. It’s assumed that because I can `su` to `root` I belong to the group `admin`. However, one not need belong to the group `admin` to execute `root` privileges — (this should probably be deleted, just responding to your comment. Thanks again. Cheers).